# Change the table that Orchard reads from

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have followed tutorial on how to write content part in Orchard CMS. 
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part

So, my content part writes the data from the backend to the record table that I wanted to, but the backend isn't reading saved custom content from the same table, i.e. when I manually change the record value in the database and refresh orchard admin, I don't see it changed.

How to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That documentation article is slightly misleading because while the code it provides does store your data in the table you created in the database, it also stores the data within Orchards document storage (xml stored in the ContentVersionRecord table, column called data I believe). So basically for fetching data it will use the document storage, for any querying/filtering it will use the data stored in your record. You can change your code so it will only store it in your table if you'd prefer.

```
public double Latitude
{
    get { return Record.Latitude; }
    set { Record.Latitude = value; }
}
```

So yeah, I shall try to update the documentation tonight because that article is particularly confusing. Have a look at Bertrand's article on Orchard's document storage model: [The Shift](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/the-shift-how-orchard-painlessly-shifted-to-document-storage-and-how-it-ll-affect-you). Useful read

And I know it's annoying to hear this, but when you are playing with Orchard, it's best to play by its rules. Is there a particular reason you need to modify data directly in the db? Or just playing around?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. I need it for my idea of implementing something :)
Now its working, thanks a lot , I appreciate your help.

Comment: Changing a forgotten admin password is one of such instances. It got me fooled for a little while too. Changing the value in the `User` table wasn't enough, I also had to change the value in the `Data` field in the `ContentItem` table.